# Action composition using @With annotation in Play framework (Java)

Tags: model-view-controller, playframework, playframework-2.0

How can I use two action compositions in Play Framework 2.4 (in Java)?

Suppose that, to avoid code duplication, I've got two actions to use :`Auth` and `LogData`.

How can I use both in an action composition?

This won't compile, causing a duplicate annotation error:

> # play.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[error:
>   duplicate annotation]

```
 @play.db.jpa.Transactional()
        @With(Auth.class)
        @With(LogData.class)
        public static Result callForumTeacher(String random, Long gameId){
               //Action code 
               return ok(Json.toJson("data"));
        }
```

This is a skeleton on how `Auth` and `LogData`  are implemented:

```
public class CheckPausedGame extends Action.Simple {

     @Override
        public F.Promise<Result> call(Http.Context context) throws Throwable {
            if (checkCondition(context)) {
                return delegate.call(context);
            } else {
                F.Promise<Result> promise = F.Promise.promise(new F.Function0<Result>() {
                    @Override
                    public Result apply() throws Throwable {
                        return redirect("/paused");
                    }
                });
                return promise;
            }
        }
    }
```

This only a skeleton omitting some methods not useful for this question.

Comment: What do you mean "it won't work"? You get an exception? Only one of the actions run? Neither of the actions run? How are "Auth" and "LogData" implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the documentation doesn't seem to clearly state this (at least I haven't found it anywhere), the intended way to use `@With` in cases like this is to pass all Actions at once (`With` takes an array)

Your code becomes

```
@play.db.jpa.Transactional()
        @With(value = {Auth.class, LogData.class})
        public static Result callForumTeacher(String random, Long gameId){
               //Action code 
               return ok(Json.toJson("data"));
        }
```

See [the api doc](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/java/index.html)

Comment: This doesn't compile, got another compilation error:

 # play.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[error: annotation values must be of the form 'name=value']

Comment: @Atropo Might have my Java syntax wrong, it's been a while since I've used it. I changed it to `value = ...`, see if that works.

Comment: Although I _think_ it should work as it was written before.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the `{ }` tested now and it works fine both ways, with or without `value`.
Thanks